# how to save tdms data to a USB stick on crio

Tags: labview

Morning,

I want to save the files to an external USB stick on CRIO, cause the internal crio system can't hold too much data.

And also, how can I log in to the internal system?I tried with ftp://, it's not working, and I can log in to the system using http:// but I can delete anything form the system.

Many thanks.

Aileen

Answer (score 0):

Your USB Drive seen on cRIO as drive U:\

Write code under cRIO and use Open TDMS.vi  connect path control and specify the path.

For internal memory it would be C:\test.tdms
For USB U:\test.tdms

Use operation input for that VI and connect there open or create constant to create test.tdms file if does not exist.

Than use TDMS write to log your data.

PS. This would be helpful for you: http://www.ni.com/tutorial/52028/en/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I am a newer, I am still a bit confused, so I have to change the path of the USB as U:\ on the control panel? and the path has been specified already on my code, there is just an indicator with path location left, so I don't know where to add the U:\test.tdms

Comment: Can you send me your example code please? I might help you looking on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save data using standard File I/O functions/VI's. You will also have to use standard windows file naming and file paths conventions such as a backslash...etc. Also as mentioned above, you will need to use u as the first drive and v as the second and so on.

This might be helpful: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P7iaSAC

Also NI support engineers can be very helpful in answering these questions.